# Material-UI Styled API: classes not applying to child elements

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to create a page in Material-UI v5.  I'm familiar with v4, getting better with v5.  But for some reason the css styles aren't applying here.

Neither my `testcss` or `loadingBox` classes have any effect.

Why are they not working?  Is there something fundamental I'm missing here?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
    Avatar, Box, CircularProgress, Fade,
    IconButton,
    Paper, SpeedDial, SpeedDialAction,
    styled, Table,
    TableBody,
    TableCell,
    TableContainer,
    TableHead,
    TableRow
} from "@mui/material";


const PREFIX = 'PageUsers';
const classes = {
    errorBox: `${PREFIX}-errorBox`,
    loadingBox: `${PREFIX}-loadingBox`,
    testcss: `${PREFIX}-testcss`,
};

const StyledFullPageLayout = styled(FullPageLayout)(({theme}: any) => ({
    [`&.${classes.errorBox}`]: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'middle',
    },
    [`&.${classes.loadingBox}`]: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'middle',
    },
    [`&.${classes.testcss}`]: {
        background: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
    },
}));

function PageWGPeers(props: any) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);

    return (
        <StyledFullPageLayout
            title={'Users'}
            className={classes.testcss}
        >
            <Fade in={loading}><Box className={classes.loadingBox}><CircularProgress /></Box></Fade>
            <Fade in={!loading && error} unmountOnExit><div>Error</div></Fade>
            <Fade in={!loading && !error && peers.length === 0} unmountOnExit><div>Empty</div></Fade>
            <Fade in={!loading && !error && peers.length > 0} unmountOnExit>Loaded</Fade>
        </StyledFullPageLayout>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testcss` class name works fine, you can apply a background-color to see it more clearly. You are passing the `loadingBox` class name to the descendant of the `StyledFullPageLayout` component so you have to use this selector:

```
'& className'
```

So change your code to:

```
// Notice I add a space after the '&'
[`& .${classes.loadingBox}`]: {
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'middle',
},
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]